# Star Trek: The Motion Picture dress uniforms

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-uniforms, star-trek-the-motion-picture

Is there any additional information regarding formal dress uniforms for Starfleet personnel, from the first motion picture?

Some could say the admiral's uniform seen in the first movie was a dress uniform, but I am curious about the same from other ranks in TMP.

Comment: I’m not entirely clear what you’re asking. Are you asking whether formal dress uniforms were designed for ranks other than Admiral for *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*, but not shown in the movie?

Comment: Formal dress uniforms were used frequently throughout all the Star Trek series.

Comment: @BBlake: Yes, but this question asks explicitly about the uniforms from the time shown in *The Motion Picture*.

Comment: Actually, if one wishes to know the answer AND see photos of the same, check out the 1701st Costume website. Just Google "1701st costume" and it will be the first site to show. Once there go to TMP forum and You will see that Yes, there was a Captain's Loden Green and white Dress Uniform that is identical to Admiral Kirk's dress uniform.

Answer (score 10):

A full set of uniforms (including Dress uniforms) were designed by the film's Costumer Designer, Bob Fletcher.

This was discussed at some length in the book "[The Making of Star Trek : The Motion Picture](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Making_of_Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture)" by Gene Roddenberry:

> Fletcher not only devised uniforms for all the crew, but, as with most
>   military services, there are several classes of uniforms.
>
> Dress uniforms are worn only on formal occassions and at Starfleet
>   Headquarters. The best example of this can be seen in Admiral Kirk’s
>   uniform worn at the beginning of the movie, with Bill Shatner wearing
>   the crisp loden green and white uniform.

[image]

Comment: I'm amazed that there's actually an answer to this question.

Comment: They've designed a full set of uniforms for each series and film; http://www.st-spike.org/pages/uniforms/2273-2277/uniforms.htm. It would be more surprising if there wasn't an answer.

Comment: +1, though it should be noted that the remark that "dress uniforms are worn (...) at Starfleet Headquarters" is an absolute exception compared to Starfleet uniforms from all other shown timeframes (which goes along with the exceptionally "modest" or "regular" look of TMP's dress uniforms).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Yes, and in the long shot of the foyer at Starfleet HQ we only see one other person in dress uniform.

Comment: That is my point exactly. In ST:TMP the only formal uniform we saw was worn by admirals. I presume formal uniforms for other ranks follow the same design as ADM Kirk's formal dress, with the exception of color.